# Forcing 1 URL to use HTTP when the whole site is forced to use HTTPS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite, https

**Background**

I have a website that is forced to use `https` like this,

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

I have one URL that has to be `http` to work. It looks like this,

```
www.example.com/mypage.html
```

or

```
example.com/mypage.html
```

**Question**

Considering the rule exists to force the whole site to `https`, how can I force the one url, in any format www or without www, to be forced into using `http`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve that you need to include a Rewrite Condition (`RewriteCond`). So you can use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mypage
```

This is basically saying that if the URL includes `/mypage` then it will **not** redirect to HTTPs and stay as HTTP. If the URL doesn't include `/mypage` then it will redirect everything to HTTPs.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mypage
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80` is working for you then continue to use it, but you can replace it with `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on`.

Make sure you clear your cache **before** testing this.